# SQL server login error remote server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am connecting to two remote databases (sql server and the databases are on the same remote machine). Both databases are in separate directories.

I checked the security settings in the SQL management console for both databases and they are the same. However, I can connect to one database remotely (using a remote connection string in my C# application) but the other database gives me "Login failed - Login failed for user XXX/ZZZ".

Any ideas why this is happening? (Could it be related to the permissions on the physical directories where the files of the database are located)?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL management console, check both Logins on the server and Users on each database.

Answer (score 1):

It is a login issue as stated by the error.  Make sure you can get to both databases uses SSMS using the logins that the C# application is using.  If this works, then it is something else.

One common problem is not changing the default database from [master] or adding the user with rights to the database you want to query.

Comment: I did notice the the default database was master. How does this affect the same login to one database and not the other?

Comment: Many times the default database is left to [master] but the user has no access to the database.  Did you change the default to your database on both servers?  Are you having any more issues?

Comment: I will have to check on monday. But the two databases on are on the same server.